# filter array of objects based on month and year

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I want to display the objects based on the current month and year

This filters the objects based on the month, I need to filter objects based on the year also.

```js
var array = [{
    title: "a",
    date: "2018-03-29"
  }, {
    title: "b",
    date: "2018-04-13"
  }, {
    title: "c",
    date: "2018-04-12"
  }, {
    title: "leave",
    date: "2018-04-11"
  }, {
    title: "d",
    date: "2018-06-16"
  }],
  currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1,
  events = array.filter(e => {
    var [_, month] = e.date.split('-'); // Or, var month = e.date.split('-')[1];
    return currentMonth === +month;
  });
console.log(events);
```

Comment: Use `year` instead of `_` and check it against the current year?

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks I'll

Comment: as in `var [year, month] = e.date.split('-'); 
        return currentYear === +year && currentMonth === +month;`

Answer (score 3):

Well to filter by `year` and `month`, you just need to get the `currentYear` along with `currentMonth`, and then get the `year` and `month` of the iterated `date`.

This is how should be your code:

```
//Get the currentYear and the currentMonth
currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1,
currentYear = new Date().getFullYear(),

//Get the year and month from the iterated date
var [year, month] = e.date.split('-');

//Then filter the dates
events = array.filter(e => {
    var [year, month] = e.date.split('-'); // Or, var month = e.date.split('-')[1];
    return (currentMonth === +month) && (currentYear == year);
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var array = [{
    title: "a",
    date: "2018-03-29"
  }, {
    title: "b",
    date: "2018-04-13"
  }, {
    title: "c",
    date: "2018-04-12"
  }, {
    title: "leave",
    date: "2018-04-11"
  }, {
    title: "d",
    date: "2018-06-16"
  }],
  currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1,
  currentYear = new Date().getFullYear(),
  events = array.filter(e => {
    var [year, month] = e.date.split('-'); // Or, var month = e.date.split('-')[1];
    return (currentMonth === +month) && (currentYear == year);
  });
console.log(events);
```

Comment: This was already answered in the first comment 20 minutes ago. Also `var [year, month] = e.date.split('-');` is not needed before the filter

Comment: @mplungjan Yes it was partially answered in this comment (which I had upvoted before making my answer), and its quite trivial to use destructing here ;)  and yes I just made a whole answer, including getting the year and the filtering. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string representation of year and month like `2018-06` and check this value as a substring in `date` property to filter out the records of current year and current month.

```js
var array = [{
    title: "a",
    date: "2018-03-29"
  }, {
    title: "b",
    date: "2018-04-13"
  }, {
    title: "c",
    date: "2018-04-12"
  }, {
    title: "leave",
    date: "2018-06-11"
  }, {
    title: "d",
    date: "2018-04-16"
  },
   {
    title: "e",
    date: "2018-06-18"
  }],
  currentMonth = '0'+(new Date().getMonth() + 1),
  currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()
  events = array.filter((e) => {
    var dateStr = currentYear+'-'+currentMonth;
    return (e.date.indexOf(dateStr) !== -1)
  });
console.log(events);
```

Comment: Why not just `var [year, month] = e.date.split('-'); 
        return currentYear === +year && currentMonth === +month;`

Comment: @mplungjan that can also be done using destructuring but this is some other alternative I am showing to OP.

Comment: Keep it simple. Adding year to the destruct was way simpler

Comment: @mplungjan true. But this could also be useful to develop logic when other user visit this or OP itself.

Comment: I have a strong feeling your solution is heavier than the number comparison including the int casting

Comment: @mplungjan that is a implicit casting and should be of same value that cost the comparison of two conditions `currentYear === +year && currentMonth === +month;` It contains two arithmetic operations and two comparison operations